# PF4J Spring - not able to load any components in the plugin other than the beans declared in configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, pf4j

We are using plugin architecture for one of our projects and we decided to use Spring pf4j for the same.
When we load the plugin via extensions - the application context is not able to find the beans created using @component in the plugin project- but the beans declared in @configuration classes are injected properly when we configure the plugin using register method - Is there anyway  to scan and load the spring components in the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

`@Component` in plugin is registered to main `ApplicationContext` via `SpringExtensionFactory`, make sure you set it up correctly in `DefaultPluginManager` correctly.

If you are going to use pf4j in SpringBoot, I would suggest you take a look [sbp](https://github.com/hank-cp/sbp) project. It is built upon pf4j and provides better integration with SpringBoot.